# Neovim lua config : New tab size isn't applied in C++ files

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm configuring Neovim 0.5 using Lua. I set the tab size to 4 in `init.lua`, and it works. But in C++ files, the tab size is 8, and I have to execute `:set shiftwidth=4`, `:set tabstop=4` and `:set expandtab` manually.
Here are the config files :

`init.lua`:

```lua
require "plugins"
require "theme"

local g = vim.g
local wo = vim.wo
local bo = vim.bo

local TAB_WIDTH = 4
bo.tabstop = TAB_WIDTH
bo.shiftwidth = TAB_WIDTH
bo.expandtab = true

wo.cursorline = true
wo.nu = true
wo.rnu = true
```

`lua/plugins.lua`:

```lua
require "paq" {
        "savq/paq-nvim";

        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig";
        "Shatur/neovim-ayu";
}
```

`lua/theme.lua`:

```lua
vim.g.ayu_mirage = true

vim.cmd("colo ayu")
```

Maybe a plugin that overrides config for C++ files ?

Comment: Classical Vim script works. Actually, the problem doesn't occur specifically in C++ file. When I run nvim with a file as first arg, it works, but when I open in nvim using `:e file` or `:tabe file`, the problem occurs.
When I delete all the config, except the 4 lines for tab width, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 26):

of course its not working

```lua
bo.tabstop = TAB_WIDTH
bo.shiftwidth = TAB_WIDTH
bo.expandtab = true
```

`bo` is a buffer specific vim variable.

when you call the above code from init.lua vim `doesnt know` to which buffer to apply these settings, because you dont mention what buffer you want the settings to apply to.

wait ... and second (which is most important)

- expandtab
- shiftwidth
- tabstop

are not buffer or window options, they are from `vim.opt`

here is my init.lua config (and its working)

```
local set = vim.opt -- set options
set.tabstop = 4
set.softtabstop = 4
set.shiftwidth = 4
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer